# SAS odbc connection without credentials

Tags: odbc, sas

I have a user defined ODBC connection called "myodbc" with username and password saved.  This was created for my by the administrator so I don't get access to the credentials.

How can I make a connection with SAS without passing in the credentials.  I would think the following work would but I get invalid username error.

```
libname mydblib odbc datasrc=myodbc;
```

I am using SAS 9.3 and do not have access to the username and password for the connection.  Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an ODBC/Connection issue, nothing to do with SAS. If it's bothering to try at all, it's probably doing it correctly as far as SAS is concerned.  I would recommend verifying with the administrator.  In the meanwhile, you could try making the same ODBC connection in Access or Excel (both can connect to ODBC sources); see if they give you the same error.

Comment: Thanks, I got it...is my syntax error. Here is what worked.
libname mydblib odbc required="dsn=myodbc;schema=mySchema";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just needed to get the syntax correct, here is what I ended up with:

```
libname mydblib odbc required="dsn=myodbc;" schema='myschema';
```

or

```
proc sql;
  connect to odbc as mycon(required="dsn=myodbc;schema=myschema");
  select * from connection to mycon(...);
quit;
```